# Cursor goes of bottom of my screen past taskbar

Tags: cursor

I have recently noticed that seemingly randomly my cursor will begin going "past" the bottom of my screen. I have no other monitors.

Nothing in display settings seems to help, it continues to happen on multiple resolutions.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work. Questions should be questions, answers should be answers. [Post an answer if you want](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). In the question you should state what OS it is about. We don't use "solved" in titles, we [accept answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: OK, you have not reacted, so I posted a community wiki answer containing you solution.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(This is the OP's solution. It has been posted as an [edit to the question](https://superuser.com/revisions/1732090/2). Despite being prompted, the OP did not write a proper answer, hence this community wiki answer.)</sup>

It was HP support assistant breaking something. I had to disable it.